# Theory of range and kernel space of transpose matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

> **Theorem 7.3.** *Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Then the equation $$A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$$
>   has a solution for every $\mathbf b \in \Bbb R^m$ if and only if the dual equation $$A^T\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$$ has a unique (only the trivial) solution. (Note, that in the second equation we have $A^T$, not $A$).*

I have some trouble to prove this theory (In book "Linear Algebra
Done Wrong" page 61). I learned about fundamental subspace of matrix and the rank theories, but I fail to link them together. Can I get some hint for this one?

Thanks.

Comment: I faithfully recreated the text in your original picture (It is much preferable to reproduce the text here using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of a linked image that can be broken, but newcomers such as yourself get a pass). Maybe the "Done Wrong" part of the book title refers to punctuation use.

Comment: You say you know about rank (and I assume nullity) theorems. Have you recognized that the first condition is saying that $A$ is a full rank matrix, while the second is saying that $A^T$ has $\mathbf 0$ kernel?

Comment: In addition to what Paul Sinclair says, it may also be useful to remember that the rank of $A$ is the same as the rank of $A^T$.

Comment: Oh, I see how it works. Thanks for your help!!!